# Discuss whether $L^p_+(\mathbb R)$ has empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $p\in [1,+\infty]$ and $L^p_+(\mathbb R)\subset L^p(\mathbb R)$ be the subset of a.e. positive functions. Discuss whether this subset has empty interior.

My answer: unless $p=+\infty$ it has always empty interior.

For $p=\infty$ consider the constants: each of them has a ball which is included in $L^p_+(\mathbb R)$. So the interior of $L^p_+(\mathbb R)$ is not empty.
For $p\neq\infty$ take $g_n(x)=f(x)$ if $|x|\leq n$ and $0$ elsewhere. Since $f$ is $L^p$, for all $\epsilon$ we have that $||f-g_n||_{L^p}=||f||_{L^p,(-\infty, n]\cup[n,+\infty)}<\epsilon$ for sufficiently great $n$. But $g_n$ is not positive. If by 'positive' we mean $\geq 0$, we can just add to $0$ a 'negative tail' whose integral goes to $0$ with $n$ (e.g. the tail of an $L^p$ negative function).

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me..................